# What are example usages of the preposition 'during' in a noun phrase?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases, noun-phrases

> I've met all my good friends *during* my stay in New York.

> The band hit the big time *during* the 1990s.

> Please remain seated *during* the performance.

Above are three example usages of the preposition 'during' as the head of an adverbial phrase in a sentence. That is, the prepositional phrases starting with 'during' in the sentences modify the verbs 'met,' 'hit,' and 'remain,' respectively.

Can the preposition 'during' also be used to link items in a noun phrase as in sentences below?

> The stage lights *during* the performance were painfully bright for the eyes.

> Same sex marriage *during* the early 1900s was strictly forbidden.

Are these sentences grammatically valid?

Comment: Yes, PPs can function as post-head modifiers in NP structure.

Comment: @BillJ thank you. Are there no exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are valid, but it would be more usual to rearrange them:

*The stage lights were painfully bright for the eyes, during the performance.

Same sex marriage was strictly forbidden, during the early 1900s.*

or

*During the performance the stage lights, were painfully bright for the eyes.

During the early 1900s, same sex marriage was strictly forbidden.*

There's nothing wrong with your original examples, though.